# while writing Linq query what return type i mentioned in take and skip

Tags: c#, linq

Here i wrote a simple Linq Query for Getting Skip and take Records from server plase Guide me what i mention in my ReturnType

```
   int pager = Convert.ToInt32(pagenumber);
        int totalRecDisplay = 10;
        var TotlaRecords = (from n in db.Employee
                            orderby n.Emp_Id
                            select n);

        var pagination = from e in TotlaRecords.Skip((pager - 1) * 10).Take(totalRecDisplay)
                          select new SomeClass
                          {
                              countRec = TotlaRecords.Count(),
                              Entity = e
                          };
        return pagination;

     }
```

SomeOtherClass

```
 public class SomeClass
    {
        public int countRec { get; set; }
        public Employee Entity { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to return an Employee (or List) then you new must be (FROM .... select new Employee() { countRec = TotalRecords.Count, Entity = e}).ToList();  Other solution would be to return an object.

Comment: @jdweng what object can i pass ...

Comment: It should be : select new SomeClass().  So you should have List<SomeClass> pagination = (from .....{}).ToList();

Comment: Why are you returning Enumerable of SomeClass should not this be a singe item with a list of Employee object.

Comment: Hint: hover the mouse cursor over the `var` keyword and it'll show the real type of the variable. Hovering over variables also show their real types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presently, you are returning an `IQueryable<SomeClass>`.

You probably don't want that. (But you may -- it depends on what you are doing with it in the calling routine, but we'll assume you don't).

You're probably better off returning a list.

```
public List<SomeClass> GetPage(string pagenumber)
{
    int pager = Convert.ToInt32(pagenumber);
    int totalRecDisplay = 10;
    var TotlaRecords = (from n in db.Employee
                        orderby n.Emp_Id
                        select n);

    var count = TotlaRecords.Count()

    var pagination = from e in TotlaRecords
                                .Skip((pager - 1) * totalRecDisplay)
                                .Take(totalRecDisplay)
                 select new SomeClass
                 {
                     countRec = count,
                     Entity = e
                 };
    return pagination.ToList();

}
```

NOTE: I replaced a hard-coded "10", and moved counting the record to where it'll only be done once.